# Хочу изучить Java на уровне junior java developer

Tags: java

Здравствуйте! 
 Я начал изучать джаву пол года назад прочел Философию джавы Эккеля, смотрел различные видео уроки и сейчас у меня есть базовые знания про ООП и синтаксис джавы , поверхностно знаком с алгоритмами и структурами данных(был предмет в универе). 
знаю(htlm , css , bootstrap )
Хотелось бы узнать какую литературу читать дальше или видеоуроки смотреть  и какие технологии изучать ?

Comment: ознакомьтесь со справкой [**на какие темы здесь можно задавать вопросы?**](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Зачем на уровне жуниор? Изучайте сразу на уровне архитектора. А то всю жизть только за харчи работать будити.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

По моему мнению лучше учится не по роликам, а на конкретном проекте. Придумываешь сам себе задачу, может на работе какую то систему хочешь видеть, и реализуешь. По мере того как , что то нужно ищешь информацию в документации, на форумах, в видео. Смотреть уроки хорошо конечно, но через пару недель все забудешь, поэтому только практика. Когда выполнишь сам одну задачу, получишь все что необходимо, опыт, навык, а все это забыть будет сложно =)

Comment: зачем давать ответ на вопрос оффтопик?

Comment: @Alex прям как http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/587342/java-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C#comment785974_587346  =))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну так я один из тех, кто тому комментарию поставил плюс :) здесь трудно спросить не похожим вопросом...

Comment: @Alex печально что там еще и плюсы \*facepalm*

Comment: @АлексейШиманский аналогичная ситуация